# How to draw certain color on QImage in format Grayscale8?

Tags: qt, qimage

I want to paint on a QImage in Format_Grayscale8 format like:

```
tmpPix=QImage(2000,1000,QImage::Format_Grayscale8);

QBrush brush=QBrush(QColor(Qt::red));
painter.begin(&tmpPix);
painter.fillRect(0,0,100,100,brush);
painter.end();

brush.setColor(QColor(Qt::blue));
painter.begin(&tmpPix);
painter.fillRect(100,100,100,100,brush);
painter.end();
```

Then I get the pixel data from the QImage:

```
uchar* data=tmpPix.bits();
qDebug("fist byte value:%d",data[0]);

data=tmpPix.scanLine(150);
qDebug("second byte value:%d",data[150]);
```

The first pixel data is 87,second is 39.So Qt::red in Format_Grayscale8 is 87,Qt::blue is 39.How can I use certain value to paint on QImage in this format?

Comment: or how Qt convert a rbga color to a grayscale color?

Comment: I figure it out that I just need to set the color of brush or pen to certain gray color,the data of pixel in grayscale image would be certain number I want then.